# Images Misaligned in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Live Resource: http://meeturgent.com/sprintally/sign-in?layout=wrike

The images should be centered on the colour bar. The layout is correct in Chrome and Firefox, but the images are misaligned in Internet Explorer. What part of our CSS needs to be modified to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: You got to show some code. We do not like going to random sites and hunting down issues.

Comment: It's hard to debug an image. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: Remove `position: absolute` from the images.

Comment: then error occurs on  Mozilla .